# Redirect requests without token (micoservice architecture)

Tags: security, microservices, wildfly-swarm

I am interessted in micoservice architecture with WildFly Swarm. I'm not sure how to reach my goal: If any service in my micoservice architecture has been called from the frontend without a security token the request should be redirected to my authService. This authService checks the credentials against LDAP/KeyCloak and returns in the best case a valid jwt token. So the frontend does not have to call my authService directly.

Ist there a solution? Or does anybody of you have a better architecture for me?

Thank you

Comment: You're wanting already captured credentials to be used for a "behind the scenes" authentication?

I'm not sure about that.

I've got examples where a UI authenticates against Keycloak and then makes calls against WF Swarm microservices, and if there is no token present the request is redirected to Keycloak for login but that requires user interaction

Comment: Thank you for the response! That means the UI the makes requests and if no valid token has been sent the UI changes to a login screen to generate a new token?

Comment: That's correct.